# Protecting file uploads from files with U+202E

Tags: php, security, file-upload, unicode

how would one detect if a user put the unicode U+202E  in their file? I dont want to accept files with that character for security reasons.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[\x{202E}]+/u", "", $str);
```

or just check if something contains U+202E

```
if(preg_match("/[\x{202E}]+/u", $str)){
```

if you want to search all U+202A-E use `[\x{202A}-\x{202E}]`

Comment: After being able to insert the U202E char to some test files , it seems php just converts to â€®. Which solves my problem but why does it do this?

Comment: Most likely because you aren't using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: yeah was just about to say this, Thanks!